# Wildcards in a string and splitting the string up after them in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string that takes on the following format:

```
TEST 1 EXAMPLE 1 BLAHBLAH
```

The number 1 can be replaced by any number and "BLAHBLAH" by any string, e.g:

```
TEST 2 EXAMPLE 99 HELLOWORLD
```

What I'd like to do is first, check if the string (which I'm receiving as 'data') starts with `TEST * EXAMPLE *` and then, split it apart so I have a new string of only whatever follows. Here's what I've tried:

```py
import fnmatch
filtered = fnmatch.filter(data, 'TEST ? EXAMPLE ?')
if filtered != "":
    str = filtered.split("EXAMPLE ",1)[1]
```

Comment: Look at the re module

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fnmatch`'s `?` matches only one single character. In your case, as you showed, the numbers can be multiple digits, e.g. `99`, so you should use `*` instead. The following worked for me:

```
import fnmatch
data = "TEST 2 EXAMPLE 99 HELLOWORLD"
if fnmatch.fnmatch(data, 'TEST * EXAMPLE *'):
    // do what you want with the data
```

[Reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fnmatch.html)

But I suggest using regex instead, in the following way:

```
import re
m = re.compile("^TEST \d+ EXAMPLE \d+.*")
data = "TEST 2 EXAMPLE 99 HELLOWORLD TRY TRY"
if m.search(data):
    print(' '.join(data.split(' ')[4:])) // or whatever you want to do
```

I think regex is a more powerful tool. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your example almost works:

```
import fnmatch
data = 'TEST 1 EXAMPLE 1 BLAHBLAH'
matches = fnmatch.fnmatchcase(data, 'TEST * EXAMPLE *')
if matches:
    rest = data.split('EXAMPLE ', 1)[1]
    print(rest)
```

Note that `fnmatch.filter()` is expecting a list as its first argument, not a string, and it also returns a list. Also, `?` matches only a single character, so you need to use `*` instead.

I'd probably use a regular expression though:

```
import re
data = 'TEST 1 EXAMPLE 1 BLAHBLAH'
match = re.search(r'^TEST \d+ EXAMPLE (\d+ \w+)$', data)
if match:
    rest = match.groups()[0]
    print(rest)
```